# Reducing UIButton size with constant centre

Tags: ios, uiview

I am trying to animate the reduction of size and width of a UIButton in this way:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^{

                             [button setFrame:CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x, button.frame.origin.y, 0, 0)];

                             [button setCenter:CGPointMake(button.frame.origin.x,  button.frame.origin.y)];
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                            ...
```

The button is reducing in size, but the centre is not constant. I would like it to close on itself, if you know what I mean, like when you delete an IOS app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CGRectInset` on the current frame to produce a new frame which is smaller (or larger) than the original while maintaining the center point.

```
[button setFrame:CGRectInset(button.frame, button.frame.size.width * 0.5, button.frame.size.height * 0.5)];
```

Comment: sorry but I didn't get it. can you provide an example?

Comment: fo you mean something like CGRect frame = [[sender view] frame];
                 frame.size.width = frame.size.width + 15;
                 frame.size.height = frame.size.height + 15;
                 [[sender view] setFrame:frame];

Answer (score 1):

Use the original center:

```
CGPoint center = button.center;
button.frame = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x, button.frame.origin.y, 0, 0);
button.center = center;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[button setCenter:CGPointMake(button.frame.origin.x,  button.frame.origin.y)];
```

Comment this one out and try. If it doesn't work get the centre point before animation and set the point exclusively as mentioned rmaddy.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try :

```
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x+button.frame.size.width/2, button.frame.origin.y+button.frame.size.height/2, 0, 0)];
```

In your code, it would be:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                             [button setFrame:CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x+button.frame.size.width/2, button.frame.origin.y+button.frame.size.height/2, 0, 0)];

                }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this and it "shrinks" the button maintaining the center throughout the animation.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:0
 animations:^{
    button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 0);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // ... remove button from super view?
}];
```